# Grails - Acegi to Spring Security - getAuthoritiesMethod

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm upgrading from grails 1.3.9/acegi to grails 2.4.2/spring security.

In acegi, I had a declared method for getAuthoritiesMethod.  This method retrieved the authorities for that person and added the actual authority name (String) to a list for return.  But getAuthoritiesMethod is no longer supported.

In the new Config, I have

grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.my.domain.principal.Authority'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.nameField='authority'

But login fails, and I see this in the session

SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION = org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority(com.my.domain.principal.Authority)

Seems like it needs the actual String name of the authority vs class here, which I would think would be derived from the declared grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.nameField.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I added a method on my com.my.domain.principal.Authority class to return the authority name (String), and changed grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.nameField to match the newMethod.